# How to query join table with jpa crud repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

How can I query the charge scheme entity to return charges based on time for example?

Here are my two entity classes.

*EDIT
Added my test code, both solutions return null for me am I doing something wrong? I feel like I'm getting closer though!

```
@Entity
public class Charge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private  Long id;
    private LocalTime time;
    private double rate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cs_id", nullable=false)
    private ChargeScheme chargeScheme;
}


@Entity
public class ChargeScheme implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="cs_id")
    private  Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="chargeScheme")
    private Set<Charge> charges;
}

 Set<Charge> charges = new HashSet<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FILE"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
                LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(values[0], formatter);
                double rate = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
                Charge charge = new Charge(chargeScheme);
                charge.setTime(time);
                charge.setRate(rate);
                charges.add(charge);
            }
            //set charges
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(4,0,0);
            chargeScheme.setChargeScheme(charges);
            chargeSchemeRepository.save(chargeScheme);
            Optional<Charge> opt = chargeSchemeRepository.findAllByCharges_TimeGreaterThan(time);
            Optional<ChargeScheme> opt2 = chargeSchemeRepository.findByChargesTimeGreaterThan(time);
            List<ChargeScheme> chargescheme = chargeSchemeRepository.findAll();
            ChargeScheme scheme = chargescheme.get(0);
            Set<Charge> cur_charges = scheme.getChargeScheme();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code lacks cascading, none of the charges are saved on this line `chargeSchemeRepository.save(chargeScheme);` . Please see my code for cascading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Requirements change

```
public interface ChargeRepo extends JpaRepository<Charge, Long> {
  List<Charge> findByTimeGreaterThan(LocalTime time);
}
```

ChargeScheme class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
public class ChargeScheme {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="cs_id")
  private  Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="chargeScheme", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  private Set<Charge> charges = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Charge class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalTime;

// cannot use @Data here because of circular ref
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Charge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private LocalTime time;
    private double rate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cs_id", nullable = false)
    private ChargeScheme chargeScheme;
}
```

---

Just completed a test with this repo:

```
public interface ChargeSchemeRepo extends JpaRepository<ChargeScheme, Long> {
  List<ChargeScheme> findByChargesTimeGreaterThan(LocalTime time);
}
```

Query in answer from @James Wagstaff is also working in my tests, but I guess you are looking for a collection result.

When using this with e.g. a RestController, you can get a paged and sorted result like this:

```
public interface ChargeSchemeRepo extends JpaRepository<ChargeScheme, Long> {
  Page<ChargeScheme> findByChargesTimeGreaterThan(LocalTime time, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried both suggestions but I'm getting null returned. Am I doing something obviously wrong? I really need the full list of charges associated with a chargescheme though rather than a collection of schemes. each scheme has 24 charge bands associated with it

Comment: Updated my answer with a new repo. You don't need to go through `ChargeScheme` because all instances of `Charge` must have a parent (not null). BR

Comment: @Elbusta: Query I suggested returns a list, not an optional. `Optional<ChargeScheme> opt2 = chargeSchemeRepository.findByChargesTimeGreaterThan(time)` should be `List<ChargeScheme> opt2 = chargeSchemeRepository.findByChargesTimeGreaterThan(time)`

Answer (score 0):

You can query join tables using the jpaRepository and querying a child table using the _ character.

For example:

```
Optional<Charge> findAllByCharges_TimeGreaterThan(LocalTime time);
```

Check out the JpaRepository interface and all of the interfaces it inherits from, it is a very powerful tool.
[Spring JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)